# Angular 2, dynamic components with their own routers?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

So I'm trying to accomplish something in Angular that I think I may need to abandon routing in order to do...

I have a handful of components that represent different pages in my app each for some task. I want the user to be able to concurrently have multiple of these pages open so that they can switch between them without losing progress (maintain component state). My idea was to implement this as tabs, and allow the user to create and tabs as needed, each one routing to a new instance of one of these page components.

My problem is that currently, the user navigates to these pages via the Router. I can't think of how to resolve navigation to multiple components simultaneously. Is it possible to do this with routing? Can I instantiate a new router for each tab created so that its router-outlet resolves independently? All of the examples of tabbed navigation I see seem to operate more like just a type of navbar where there is a fixed tab always open for each page and the component state is not maintained when navigating between them.

I'm guessing I may just need to abandon routing for this, and just have a parent "Tabbed window" component at a single route endpoint, which instantiates child components for each tab and keeps track of which one to render... I think I know how I would accomplish this but if someone knows a good way to go about it I wouldn't mind seeing examples. Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want your state to persist across your tabs (using child routes I assume?) and that when you switch between tabs, you want the state to remain as you left it? Have you tried look into something like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/)? Or if your app isn't that large, implementing your own by the use of Services?

Comment: @Rcdlb I guess that answers my question, I was just wondering if there were a way in vanilla angular+routing, to dynamically instantiate a new router and provide it to each tab so that the user could route to different pages within each tab and not affect other tabs... It appears not. I'll look into NgRx but I think I'll just need to dynamically add the tabs and pages as child components instead of just making them available at route paths.

Comment: If you're application isn't that huge (both in terms of how many tabs and in general) then you can probably get away with child components.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.